# Find all natural numbers $a,b,c$ such that $abc+ab+c=a^3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all positive integers $a,b,c$ such that

$$abc+ab+c=a^3$$

My try:

Clearly $c=ak$

$abk+b+k=a^2$

$b=\frac{a^2-k}{ak+1}$ is an integer but I am not getting anything further

Comment: Is there some more background for this question?

Comment: @ILUA what if $ak+1$ divide $a^2-k$??

Comment: Other way: $$(c+1)(ab+1)=(a+1)(a^2+a+1)$$

Comment: @AsdrubalBeltran I have tried this but I didn't find it useful. and by the way it is $(a^2-a+1)$

Comment: Well, it gives you $c=a, b=(a-1)$ as solutions at least.

Comment: Yes or $b=1$  and $c=a^2-a$

Comment: You should change the title if you require positive solutions. The natural numbers include $0$, which admits the solution $c=0$ with $b=a^2$ for arbitrary $a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\begin{align}
abc+ab+c &=a^3 \\
a|c, \text{ set } c=ak \hspace{2in} \\
a^2bk + a(b+k) &=a^3 \\
abk+(b+k)&=a^2 \\
a^2-abk-(b+k) &= 0
\end{align}$

$$a = \frac{bk + \sqrt{b^2k^2+4(b+k)}}{2}$$

$\to$ integer when $b^2k^2+4(b+k)$ is square. This has the same parity as $bk$ so the sum is even.

---

Note also that $(bk+2)^2 = b^2k^2 + 4bk+4 = b^2k^2 + 4(bk+1)$

So we need $(b+k)\geq(bk+1) \\
\Rightarrow  (b-1) \geq (bk-k) = k(b-1) \\
\Rightarrow k=1 \text{ or } b-1=0$

Therefore for any $a$, the possible answers are:

- $ b=1, c=(a^2-a)$
- $b= (a-1), c=a$

Comment: Does this answer account for the numerator being even?

Comment: Note that $(bk)^2 < b^2 k^2 + 4b+4k < b^2k^2 + 2bk + 1 = (bk+1)^2$ "most of the time"

Comment: @Joffan now what??

Comment: @Myself answer updated with parity-based improvement to your observation, thanks